# Does data intellect's TorQ framework allow for different permissions across environments?

Tags: kdb, torq

We have our app running in 4-5 different environments.

Each env has different permissions (we have users who can use everything in dev, certain things in uat and nothing in prod)

I looked at the torq framework and I cannot see a way to differentiate between environments.

What would be the best approach here ?

1. Have functions_DEV.q, functions_UAT.q
2. within each file, have a env column to determine which row is kept and which row isn't?

Answer (score 0):

The installtorqapp.sh script included with TorQ (http://dataintellecttech.github.io/TorQ/InstallGuide/#parameters-used) has functionality for running environment specific scripts during deployment, it will copy the appropriate torq and app code for you (in the example they are using the base TorQ and TorQFSP code), but it has an optional 'env' parameter which can be used to run env specific code, so you could have config settings specific to each environment.